# Что использовать вместо webhook(telegram)?

Tags: telegram, webhook

max_connections (Telegram Webhook) - Максимальное значение которое можно установить - 100.
Но мне этого мало, можно использовать что-то другое?)

Answer (score 0):

В таком случае используйте [Long Poll](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getupdates)

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).